# Making a pointer from another class point to 'this'

Tags: c++

I'am working on a very basic C++ 2D game engine. I created a class called GameObject and every game object will have a component list. Each component also has a GameObject pointer that points to the very gameobject that it belongs to. Basically like this:

```
class Component{   
public:
        virtual void start() {};
        virtual void update(float dt) {};
        GameObject* obj;
};

class GameObject
{
private:
    std::vector<Component*> components;
public:
    void addComponent(Component* c)
    {
        c->obj = this;
        components.push_back(c);
    }
};
```

### However the code above is giving me bunch of errors:

> -unexpected tokens(s) preceding ;    -syntax error: missing ';'
> before *
>
> -'obj' is not a member of 'Component'
>
> -missing type specifier- int assumed. Note c++ does not support
> default int

and all my errors just go away if i just delete the GameObject pointer.

What exactly is the problem here ?

Comment: You need forward declaration.

Comment: Frward declare class GameObject; before Component

Comment: Work on the errors in the same order they are reported ... fix one thing, then recompile.  Repeat.  Your first error is "error: ‘GameObject’ does not name a type"

Comment: You probably need to turn on more warnings ... here are my defaults when working on new code:  
g++ -std=c++17 -m64 -ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -Werror=vla -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wsign-promo -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Wold-style-cast -Wreturn-type -Woverloaded-virtual -Wsequence-point -Wdelete-incomplete -Wuninitialized -Wmisleading-indentation -Wunreachable-code -Wnon-virtual-dtor -MMD -MP

Comment: @2785528 OP already have an error, more warnings will not help. Also, you have both `-O3` and `-O0`.

Comment: The next compiler report includes the 'virtual' methods (with no virtual destructor) warnings.  IMHO, warnings Always help.  When both -O3 and -O0 are in the option list, the later option overrides the previous (on g++), so not a problem. It is a convenience for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward declare the `GameObject` class

```
#include <vector>

class GameObject;

class Component {
 public:
  virtual void start() {}
  virtual void update(float dt) {}
  GameObject* obj;
};

class GameObject {
 private:
  std::vector<Component*> components;

 public:
  void addComponent(Component* c) {
    c->obj = this;
    components.push_back(c);
  }
};
```

Comment: Does that mean that  the Component class is being created before the GameObject class so the GameObject type is invalid when it's created ?

Comment: @HyperMelon no. You have to let the compiler know that `GameObject` is going to be a class. Otherwise there is no way for the compiler to know what it is.

Comment: @HyperMelon --  So far, this code is only declaring a couple of classes.  There is no code invoking either ctor.